# oneliner using reduce in python

Tags: python-3.x, reduce, one-liner

I'm trying to take my Python skills (beginner) to the next level.
and I'm trying to teach myself the functools.reduce() function

So I'm running every time into the same error;
I'd appreciate if someone could explain to me what is the problem in my code

I'm trying to build a simple func that receive a number and return the sum of number digits

```
import functools
def sum_using_reduce(number):
    return str(number)[0] + str(number)[1]
number = 104
print(functools.reduce(sum_using_reduce, number))
```

Comment: `reduce()` needs an iterable (list, str, ...) as second arg, but `number` is an int (not iterable)

Comment: I get this error:
TypeError: sum_using_reduce() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: while tring to use number = '104'

Comment: https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce
Seems like the function must need two args.
Maybe try `def sum_using_reduce(a,b): return int(a)+int(b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
number = 104
functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [int(i) for i in str(number)])
```

Output: `5`

Using your example:

```
import functools


def sum_using_reduce(x, y) -> int:
    return x + y


print(functools.reduce(sum_using_reduce, [int(i) for i in str(105)]))
```

Output: `6`

Another approach:

```
import functools


def sum_using_reduce(number: int) -> int:
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [int(i) for i in str(number)])


print(sum_using_reduce(124))
```

Output: `7`

Comment: thank you very much!
I thought I could solve it without using Lambda func and without changing the function parameters. which mean, func will accept only one number, while using only one line, and without lambda. but I guess this is the most simple and elegant way.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `sum_using_reduce` function you are trying to sum two strings, which would simply perform concatenation. Moreover, you are providing an integer as the second argument to the reduce function, where the reduce function requires an iterable to be provided.

Below is a solution that fixes both these requirements:

```python
from functools import reduce
number=104
print(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,map(int,str(number))))
```

`map(int,str(number))` transforms the number to a string (104->"104") and then turns every character in the string to an integer, returning an iterable map object ("104"->[1,0,4]).

`lambda x,y:x+y` is a function which takes two integers and sums them.